# What kind of syntax is this (yaml, ini, ...)?

Tags: syntax

Could anybody help me figure out the syntax of the code below?

```
"AddonInfo"
{
        "name"              "Addon name"
        "version"           "Current Version"
        "up_date"           "Date of update"
        "author_name"       "Addon's Author"
        "author_email"      ""
        "info"              "Addon's Info"
        "override"          "0"
}
```

Comment: Nothing I've seen before.  Not YAML, not INI.  It's almost JSON, but there are no colons or commas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Half-Life 2 (to be specific, garrys mod) Configuration File. I think it's only used by the source engine.

**Edit:**

A simple regexp to convert to JSON:

```
config_str.gsub(/(")\s*"(.*?)"/, '\1: "\2",').gsub(/(".*?")\s*{/, '\1: {')
```

Where `gsub` is the function for global replacement.

Comment: Is there a way to parse this with regex?

Comment: regular expressions are not for parsing, but see my edit on how to convert to JSON.

Comment: Yep, I've seen such files in some of Prtal 2's .vpk archives. :)

Comment: I like these puzzles.* Give me another one!

* Is this the correct english word for this? Or is riddle or mystery better?

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a custom configuration file used by whatever system you're currently looking at?

JSON would have colons as Josh has pointed out